Unable to query transactions on ink contracts using !@Polkadot/api-contract
I am having troubles querying my smart contract transaction using the @polkadot/api-contract. I have a NextJS application setup and I have a private key that can be used to sign transactions. I have setup my code as the image below to initialize the contract and also query a message on it.
import { ApiPromise } from "@polkadot/api";
import { ContractPromise } from "@polkadot/api-contract";


When I call the verifyUser function, I get an error that I can't decode so I'm not entirely sure what the problem is.


The module: error: "0x02000000" is indicating to me that it's a ModuleError. So an error returned by a pallet, in this case the pallet_contracts.
You can decode this module error as described here: https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/cookbook/tx#how-do-i-get-the-decoded-enum-for-an-extrinsicfailed-event
Once we know the actual error returned by the pallet we now more how to fix it. :)
